# Android ksoap2 web service deprecated error

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I want to use ksoap2 as SOAP web service for Android.

I use http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data this example to begin with ksoap2. When  import latest file and paste this code

```
     private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/TopGoalScorers";
 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu";
 private static final String URL = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL";


    public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
   request.addProperty("iTopN", "5"); //variable name, value. I got the variable name, from the wsdl file!
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request
   AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  
   httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
   httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
   SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
   return result;
}
```

call

```
SoapObject result=soap(METHOD_NAME, SOAP_ACTION, NAMESPACE, URL);
```

I receive this error (example display error):
The type AndroidHttpTransport is deprecated

Can some one tell me where I'm wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tutorial you followed is outdated. Use `HttpTransportSE` in place of `AndroidHttpTransport`.